# sending json obj to polymer element

Tags: javascript, json, polymer

I have no idea why is this happening!
i want to send an object to polymer element and then use it.
im using something like this for the element

```
<polymer-element name="post-thumb" attributes="post">
  <template>
    <article>
      <span>this is a post thumb</span>
        <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </article>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('post-thumb');
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

and after HTML import, i'm calling it like this:

```
<post-thumb post='{"title":"post title 1","body":"post body"}'> </post-thumb>
```

it's weird cause when i use {{post}} it'll bring back the whole  {"title":"post title 1","body":"post body"} but when i use {{post.title}} polymer simply returns nothing!

what's wrong here!? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to hint to the polymer that the attribute is of object type, ie try

```
<script>
Polymer('post-thumb', {
   created: function() { 
      this.post = {};
   }
}
);
</script>
```

Comment: Here's the relevant section of the docs: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#configuring-an-element-via-attributes